# How to run ajax only when jquery ui radio button is unchecked or not active?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have jquery ui radio buttonset in my html code like this -

```
<form id="frm_time_slots-1" action="" method="post">
<div class="div_time_slots ui-buttonset">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="hid_time_slots_id">
<input id="radtimeslot1-1" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" name="rad_time_slots_status">
<label class="ui-state-active ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left" for="radtimeslot1-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<input id="radtimeslot2-1" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="radio" value="0" name="rad_time_slots_status">
<label class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right" for="radtimeslot2-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
</div>
</form>
```

And I am running some ajax request on clicking these radio buttons. But i dont want to run ajax request when the button is already checked/selected i.e. active. i want to run the ajax code only when it is not being checked i.e. when it is at its default state. Here is my ajax code -

```
$(".div_time_slots input[type='radio']").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            // rest code...
            });
```

So what selector either css or jquery should i have to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Before start calling ajax add this function to check radio button is checked or not.

```
if ($("#radtimeslot1-1").prop("checked")) {
 // do something
  return false;
} else {
  //your ajax function
}
```

Comment: not working! i changed my code to  $(".div_time_slots input[type='radio']").click(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked"))
  {
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
// ajax code

and else condition is not working.

Comment: alert is coming whether radio button is checked or not - clicking on "ON" and "OFF" radio button brings alert.   if($(this).prop("checked"))
  {
   alert(123);
   return false;
  }

Comment: why the alert always show true whether i click on ON radio button or OFF radio button?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".div_time_slots input[type='radio']").click(function(){
if(!$(this).prop("checked")){
     $.ajax({
        // rest code...
        });
}
```

Comment: i think its "checked" rather that ":checked" if we use it in prop().

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that button is checked using `jQuery property` i.e. `prop`

> Prop get the value of a property for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched
>   element

Go throught this [Documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)